# Установка с помощью packer. Постустановочный скрипт

Tags: debian

Устанавливаю debian с помощью packer. После установки должен сработать скрипт postinstall.sh. Но он не срабатывает, так как после первого запуска система просит логин и пароль. Может быть, я что-то не дописал в файле .json?
Фрагмент файла json:

```
.............
      "ssh_username": "user",
      "ssh_password": "user",
      "ssh_port": 22,
 .............
      }
    }
    ]
   }
  ],
"provisioners": 
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "script": [
            "postinstall.sh",
            "apt-get -y install mc"

},
]
}
```

Скрипт:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install mc
```

Еще способ есть, написать в json так:

```
"provisioners": 
        {
    "type": "shell",
            "inline": [
                "apt-get update",
                "apt-get -y install mc"
```

Но тоже не работает

Answer (score 0):

У вас не в порядке скобки.

```
"provisioners": [
  {
   "type": "shell",
   "inline": [
     "sleep 30",
     "sudo apt-get update",
     "sudo apt-get install -y nano mc "
   ]
  }
]
```

Все это будет работать при условии, что вы перед этим добавили вашего пользователя `user` в группу `sudo`

Так-же можно использовать опцию validate:

```
packer validate -var-file=vars.json debian.json
```

Помогает убрать некоторое кол-во ошибок.